# PHP extensions not found via httpd but are found from CLI, with the same php.ini

Tags: php, apache, command-line-interface, php-extension

I wanted to use some extensions of PHP 7.1 after installing it and Apache 2.4 and on my Windows 7. I wrote a small test script `index.php` to call some functions of the given extensions.

```
<?php
    var_dump(mb_strlen('p'));
    var_dump(mysqli_connect_error());
```

and uncommented the appropriate lines from the `php.ini`, like

```
...
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
...
```

and configured the extension_dir according to the windows-specific part of the `php.ini`

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
; extension_dir = "ext"

extension_dir = "ext"
```

I restarted the Apache web server and fetched the http://localhost/index.php. I got the error messages:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_strlen() in C:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs...**

which means the extension was not loaded.

I doublechecked that the `php.ini` I made the modifications in is the same as the `phpinfo()` displayed in the browser:

```
Loaded Configuration File    C:\Program Files\php\php.ini
```

On the contrary, if I started the same index.php not via web server but from the command line then I got different output:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs>"C:\Program Files\php\php.exe" index.php
int(1)
NULL
```

which means the extensions were loaded properly.

The command line PHP uses the same `php.ini`:

```
c:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs>php -i|find "Loaded Configuration File"
Loaded Configuration File => C:\Program Files\php\php.ini
```

How can it be that the *same* `php.ini` file loads the extensions from command line but does not load them when used via the web server?

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to the description in the php.ini, the `extension_dir` should be specified with a full path, not just a relative one. Changing the line in `php.ini` from

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

to

```
extension_dir = "C:/Progra~1/php/ext"
```

and restarting the web server solved the problem.

NB: I used the DOS-8.3 path instead of `"C:/Program Files/php/ext"` because according to the php-7.1.11-Win32-VC14-x64.zip\install.txt manual, it does not like paths containing spaces:

*You may choose a different location but do not have spaces in the path (like C:\Program Files\PHP) as some web servers will crash if you do.*

The path I referred to doesn't contain any spaces so I don't think I did anything wrong. Despite this, I am not sure how it would work if I had installed php to the default directory c:\php but it seems that defining the full path is a more secure way.

Comment: hello sir. I have a similar problem, which is not being solved with the proposed solution ... Can you have a look at [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59530576/sqlite3-and-pdo-sqlite-not-loaded-in-php-apache2-localhost-but-loaded-in-php-cmd) question?

Answer (score 0):

Check which modules is Apache using:

- go to your apache config. IE: `cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled`
- list enables modules`ls -lsai php*` (in my case, prev version was enabled)
- remove previous modules (IMC: `rm php*`)
- enable needed module. IMC:

  - `sudo ln -s ../mods-available/php7.4.load`
  - `sudo ln -s ../mods-available/php7.4.conf`
- reload apache (IMC: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`)
- use `print/dump phpinfo();` to check which php module  Apache is runnig

Command in example will work on Linux/Unix machines. Not on windows I'm afraid